# Tensorflow Speech Recognition, run sess.run fails with "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition

I have trained a model according to the instructions at: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition#training

I have got a ckpt file but wasnt able to freeze it and generate a PB using tensorflow's official instructions.

In order to create the PB file I have converted the pbtxt, using the following converter:
https://github.com/irfansharif/tensorflow/blob/master/converter.py

now when running the Tensorflow official "label_wav_file" I am getting the following error:

> 2018-08-02 10:15:12.263821: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   FMA Traceback (most recent call last):   File "label_wav.py", line
>   134, in 
>       tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))   File "label_wav.py", line 106, in main
>       FLAGS.output_name, FLAGS.how_many_labels)   File "label_wav.py", line 100, in label_wav
>       run_graph(wav_data, labels_list, input_name, output_name, how_many_labels)   File "label_wav.py", line 68, in run_graph
>       predictions, = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {input_layer_name: wav_data})   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 900, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1104, in _run
>       np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py",
>   line 531, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'RIFF$}\x00\x00WAVEfmt
>   \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00

I want sure about the layers that i am suppose to use as my input and output layer(I am suspecting this is as the root for the problem)

Input Layer: data/Mul:0
Output Layer: ArgMax:0

(I have selected the following as Output layer as it was set as such in the pbtxt file)

I have the following layers exist in my graph:
[image: my network structure from tensorboard]

any ideas what are the correct layers or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your traceback:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: **b'RIFF$}\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00**

You're trying to feed your network a file read as a string of bytes, that will not work. The layer you chose as input expects a `float` matrix of some shape, which is not what you're dealing with.
You'll need to study the network architecture to understand how data is passed in and what's the input preprocessing you need to do in order to be able to feed the data in the network

Comment: At the moment I am using the default (again - just using the TF built-in example):
with open(wav, 'rb') as wav_file:
    wav_data = wav_file.read()

Comment: Indeed, "RIFF..." is the beginning of a Wav header. Looking at the training scripts, though, you'll find out that there is a lot of transformation happening to `wav_data` before it enters the layer you chose as input. You need to replicate exactly those transformations

Comment: I was thinking that the official example will work out of the box.. :( can you direct me to where it is? because I dont see anything about it in the train.py itslef, the test_label_wav.py however contains the following: "contrib_audio.encode_wav(sample_data, 16000)" which adding it gives me the same exact error message